# Ajax not working on Laravel 5.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I just started learning Laravel 5.5 to explore a much "advanced" framework. I have worked using Codeigniter and loved it. Now I am implementing a small CRUD functionality and it works fine. Now I am trying to use Jquery AJAX so it doesn't have to refresh. I have used Jquery AJax before on my previous codeigniter projects. Now when I try it using Laravel, it just does't work. I have checked many references, but I am not sure why its not succeeding.
I am trying to implement it to the Delete function, if I have that working, I'm sure I can do the rest.

**THE PROBLEM:**

1. When I try to delete it, it redirects to a 'json' view. I presume thats because of the `return response ()->json ($post);` But yes the item deletes.
2. When I check the developer console, there is no AJAX request being made. I think the AJAX doesn't get called, it just goes straight to the form's action.

**How I want it to be**

1. The AJAX works. No need for a page refresh.

**Controller**

```
    public function destroy($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    if (auth()->user()->id !== $post->user_id){
      return redirect ('/posts')->with('error', 'Unauthorized page');
    }
    $post->delete();
    return response ()->json ($post);
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
```

**View**

```
{!!Form::open(['action'=>['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method'=>'POST', 'class'=>''])!!}
                            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
                            {{Form::button('Delete', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger delete','id' => 'delete', 'data-id' => $post->id ] )}}
                          {!!Form::close()!!}
```

**JS**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".delete").on('click',function(event){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
    $.ajax({
      url: "posts/"+id,
      type: "DELETE",
      success: function(){
        alert("DELETED");
      }
    });
  });
});
  </script>
```

Thank you so much friends!!

Comment: You can likely prevent the default action of the button (which is to submit the form) by calling `event.preventDefault()`  in your click handler.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are submitting the form before firing away your `REST` call, so your rest call never gets off, but the page reloads, because the form has been submitted and you then show the json which you returned from your controller.

**Solution**

Remove your `Form` in the blade view. Then update ajax as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var id = {!! $post->id !!};
   $.ajax({
      url: "posts/"+id,
      type: "DELETE",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         alert("DELETED");
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
It also turned out, that my Jquery script had AJAX removed, maybe because it was a slim min?

Much love!!